# Adding in information from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, countif

Good Morning,

I have a spreadsheet with 40,000 products and a spreadsheet with 35,000 products all with item ID's

Is there anyway I can add in the missing 5,000 ITEM ID's using a forumla? I dont want to manually go through each item and see what is missing

Thank you very much for your time and help

Cheers

Comment: Do you intend to keep both spreadsheets synchonised in some way or is this a one off operation?

Comment: This is a one off operation my friend.

Answer (score 0):

If ColumnA holds the unique ID's in each sheet please try:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1)
```

in Sheet2 and

```
 =COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1)
```

in Sheet1, both copied down to suit.

Then sort both on the results of these columns and copy those that result in `0` from one sheet to the other to ensure complete sets in both sheets and to check whether either sheet has duplicates.

Comment: I am slightly confused with this method? Any further explanation?

Comment: I will give you a bit more information.... column A in my first excel document has 35,000 unique ID's and column A in my second spreadsheet has 40,000 unique ID's I need to find which ones are missing in my first spreadsheet out of the 40,000

Comment: When I do the formula is comes up with an open excel document box? I have placed the forumla in a random cell in excel

Comment: I suspect some confusion as to sheets within the same workbook as opposed to two separate workbooks.

Comment: If OP says two spreadsheets I suspect he means two separate documents hence what appears to be an open file dialog. Either move one sheet into the same workbook as the other or adjust the reference to Sheet2!  to account for the file name?

Answer (score 0):

next to column "A" in your longer list, put a formula in cell `B1` assuming your data starts from `A1`:
`=if(isna(VLOOKUP(A1,**column A of first shorter list**,1,false)),"Missing","Exists")`

and populate down until the end of the list, the entries reading "missing" are the ones that are missing from the first list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your list of source IDs lays in `Sheet1!A2:A40001`, row 1 is for headers. The target IDs are in `Sheet2!A2:A35001`

1. **Detect which are missing.**
   Use the following formula in `Sheet1!B2`: 
   `=MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$35001,0)`

   Copy down to `Sheet1!B2:B40001`.
2. **Filter out those already present.** 
   Select row `Sheet1!1:1`. Use *Data* -> *Filter*. Go to the drop-down arrow in cell B1, and select only `#N/A`.
3. **Copy those missing.** 
   Select all values shown in column `Sheet1!A:A`. Copy, and paste below the last value in column `Sheet2!A:A`.

It is easy to figure out how to do the same if you have adjacent columns with relevant data that you want to copy as well.